# Newbie question: Want to call an API url (using GET method) and process the answer I get

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm new to this site (as a writer. I'm a long time silent-reader..), and doing my first steps in writing simple VB.NET winform/console applications, using VS 2010 system.

I want to start with writing a simple program that will use an API I have access to, for sending SMS messages.
AFAIK, I have to send a GET request, and I should get back a string from the service telling me "Success" or an error code.

I'm sure the idea of sending an URL call is simple and probably asked before me many times.

But nevertheless - I'll appreciate help to start this from scratch and making this to work.

Many thanks at advance!

Comment: When you `POST` something to a server, right after you get and read the response. As a `StatusCode` or something possibly different (as a JSON). With both [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) and [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest). This depends on the API of the service you're using (it's all, usually, well documented).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the Api's have documentation that'll tell you specifically what languages can interact with their api's.  More than likely, vb.net isn't on that list, but you can use another language, (probably something like python) to nail down a small script, then use vb to interact with the output.